# Laravel Using Stale Files?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.7

I have a Laravel project that was generating errors, so I deleted the offending line, pushed the code to the repository, pulled the code onto the production server and retried. However, I'm still getting the exception referencing the line of code which no longer exists.

1. I checked the production server, and the most recent code is present.
2. I did `composer dumpautoload`
3. I did `php artisan clear-compiled`
4. I did `php artisan optimize`
5. I did `php artisan cache:clear`

But the Whoops handler is still giving me errors on files that have clearly changed. What to do?

Comment: Did you try by restarting the server?

Comment: No need to restart server. OP confirm that the line is in fact not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing I failed to mention in the question is that the problem was in a queued job. Once I realized that queued jobs don't reset when the code updates, I had to issuse

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

And then it worked. Thanks for everyone's belp.

Answer (score 0):

I am normally using these four commands, If I get such errors.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Here you didn't use `php artisan view:clear` so I suggest to try this one also

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reset the opcode cache if your server having it. You can see here

http://php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-reset.php